# How to use Hub distance in a processing model?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I am trying to make line layer (hub distance layer ) between two point layer in QGIS 2.16.

It works fine when I make layers step by step but, I want to make MODEL in processing modeler and automaticly make final layer.

I got an error message like this.
[image]

[image]
[image]

This is a result of what I want.
[image]

Comment: Is ghnn the name of an attribute of the hub layer?

Comment: Yes, ghnn is the name of an attribute of the hub layer

Comment: There is no log text.

Comment: I rebuilt your model and it works fine here. Can you share your data? Which input data formats do you use?

Comment: Can you show screenshot of model. Vector data I used. I dont have data on this computer. What was wrong?

Comment: My model looks exactly like yours ...

Comment: Where I'm wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42897/discussion-between-nagib-and-underdark).